What parameters on the data sheets should I be looking at for LVP given I have a flat and stable subfloor
There are so much marketing for LVP and I am just trying to figure out what parameters I should be looking at on the data sheets for a successful install.
The subfloor slab
<1mm flatness in 8'
3/8" sloped over 22'
Hardened with Lithium Silicate after 28 days
low water emissions from concrete
concrete is slightly below grade so temperature is stable
Looking for in LVP
Herringbone pattern - We like it
Good Static load resistance (usually measured in how many PSI causes certain deflection) - will have 1500 lb safe that sits on a thick rubber mat)
Abrasion resistance (Wear layer resistance to scratching) - Kids mostly and casters (though will use a plastic protector)
5.5-8 mm thickness (to match existing tile)
Gen Notes/Rambling:
With how flat the floor is, I think the locking mechanism won't be under as much strain... however with thermal cycling the heavy weight of a safe would keep the floor fairly static and the rest of the floor would have to move.  I think its minimal with the slab being slightly below grade.
I have looked at the following parameters
Static Load Test - a psi that causes 0.005" compression in the flooring
Maximum weight of item allowed in warranty - example was 1500 lbs, but no surface area was given.


With floors weight is usually pounds per square foot.  A flat base as more square feet than something on four small legs.  With very heavy objects, people will use thick plywood under the legs to reduce the pounds per square foot.

A 100 lb woman will exert 400PSI when walking in stiletto heels with a 1/4" point at the heel. If your 1500 lb safe is tall, but shallow and narrow, it's going to exert more PSI on the floor than if it's short, wide & deep. Presuming, of course, that it sits flat on the floor, not on feet. Calculate the actual PSI of the safe before you start worrying about it.

Also, good that you're teaching your kids about tools at a young age!

The safe ideally should be putting less than 3 psi on the floor. In reality, there will be higher pressure and lower pressure spots since the surfaces are not truly flat and will deflect. The rubber mat gets this differential much smaller..but I was more worried about it essentially locking the pieces under it into no sude movement during thermal expansion/contraction cycles.........thanks, the daughter loves to help even though it slows work down for the moment.

I have been installing LVP and LVT for about 15 years. To satisfy most all of your needs practically any LVP 6mm and thicker will perform well.
Of course the thicker the wear layer the longer it will last. Your description of use is within that which is commonly expected. So you should have no issues.
Your safe on a rubber mat will also allow the floor to perform as expected.
LVP is very stable and reaction to humidity with expansion or contraction is very minimal. That should be no concerne.
The one issue I see is the herringbone pattern.  Not all LVP is manufactured to allow it to be laid in that pattern. You will need to consult the retailer and have a knowledgeable person answer this question, or consult the manufacturer.   I have encountered LVP laid in a herringbone pattern, but the ends of the boards had to be cut and possibly the tongues of the perpendicular mating boards. The ends had to be glued down. Obviously more labor is involved and having some of the floor glued and some floating will lend to more possible issues.  My advice is if it won't click together per the manufacturers instructions, don't do it.

Good catch on the herringbone pattern match.  Did a floor a few years ago as a first timer.  Was not bad, but did have to think which end I had to cut off, a couple of times.

Absolutely correct, the herringbone comes with the short ends having clickins swapped  in 50% of the planks and usually the end triangles have to be glued to the previous piece.....labor intensive but I like the style.

I did get a message from cortec and they recommended gluing under the safe and the first two rows outside of the contact point...it's med sized room,.so my concern for thermal expansion is not high....now the main issue is finding a style the wife likes, which is only flipper medium grey, which will probably not age well with style IMHO (I could be wrong)

Most all the companies recommend not installing the flooring under cabinets. However I have installed LVP in a number of properties and then installed the cabinets.  There has been no ill effects. It has been 4 years in the longest property and still no problems.  The expansion and contraction is extremely minimal. I don't believe the safe will be an issue.

I spoke with Shaw (coretec) and they gave me the ok, but with gluing down the section where the heavy safe would be and they also recommended shimming the safe so it doesn't have as many local compression spots and airflow.  Originally was going to use herringbone from Coretec Plus Carthage Oak (as there still is a supply though its been discontinued).  but its "too red" for her taste.  There is no good herringbone LVP in grey on the market I can find.
